# importing data into ALREADY CREATED mySQL database

Tags: mysql, excel, import-from-excel

PROBLEM: importing data into ALREADY CREATED mySQL database

I've done a lot of search online and know that I can import a CSV file into phpmyadmin in order for the table to be automatically created but I have created an empty table with the exact same fields as the CSV file but would like to just import the data itself.

The reason I don't want the import function to create the table for me is because I have created my table with certain restrictions/data types that arent correctly created when I do the import.

so basically, my question is, is there a way I can import data directly into an already created table (without having to manually write the 'INSERT INTO....' statements)?

Is there a piece of software that will convert spreadsheet data into an insert statement?

Thanks very much for your help!
Theresa

Comment: I don't see the problem. If your're dealing with an CSV file, there will be no table structure, except sometimes fields list in the first line. you can easily strip that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give either of these a whirl:

Navicat - [http://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat_mysql/mysql_overview.html](https://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat-for-mysql)

or

Heidi - [http://www.heidisql.com/](https://www.heidisql.com/)

Navicat is a licensed product (i.e. paid for). Heidi is open source.

EDIT: Forgot to mention that certainly within Navicat you can import from Excel to a pre-defined table.

Comment: Thanks so much!!  Navicat did it with ease :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're just dealing with a CSV file, the answer will be, from your PHP code,use mysql's native [LOAD DATA](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)  :

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'yourfile.csv' INTO TABLE tbl_name
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `LOAD DATA INFILE` syntax to load data into a table from a CSV file. Or from the shell `mysqlimport` which essentially does the same thing.

Check out the documentation here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html